# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, devise

I'm getting errors like this:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:slide) { build :slide }
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "albums" does not exist at character 13
   : INSERT INTO "albums" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

in some random way - sometimes all passes successfully and sometimes some of them don't. I'm getting those usually for same set of tests but when I run only them then I can't reproduce the problem.

I just moved to Postgres as I started to use `gem devise` and `gem apartment` for multi-tenancy which works best with schemas. Since then I added to my tests `around` hook to simulate user login:

```
  given(:user) { create :user }

  around :each do |scenario|
    login_and_switch_schema user
    scenario.run
    destroy_users_schema user
    destroy_user user
  end
```

all above helpers are defined at **spec/support/auth_helpers.rb**.

I'm not sure what else is important to dig into it so I just made a commit to [github here](https://github.com/pawel7318/footoo/tree/e85ac9b3cbb80184092c0318fef4f1f988af1790).

I'm testing it with:

```
rake db:test:prepare && rspec -X ./spec/models/ ./spec/controllers/ ./spec/features/
```

(turning off `spork` doesn't help).

Any ideas ? I feel dizzy looking at it without a clue what to do. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I don't get those errors anymore after changing `around` hook for every spec file to:

```
before(:all) do
  @user = create :user
end

after(:all) do
  destroy_users_schema @user
  destroy_user @user
end

before(:each) do      
  login_and_switch_schema @user
end
```

at the same time it works twice as fast. Anyway this is more like a workaround as root cause still stays as puzzle for me.

Comment: One more thing which I didn't checked yet is to try it without `database_cleaner`. I set all `js: true` tests as `pending` as I have some other issues with them as well (I already found the reason but had no time to fix it yet) so it can be done for that moment.

Comment: Sounds like you have some test data hanging around between some tests, or not being set up correctly.  rspec runs the tests in a random order which is why it only happens some of the time.  Also explains why running the failing test individually will pass.  It's not easy to find the offender; try splitting up the tests into smaller chunks (running a passing chunk several times to be sure it doesn't fail randomly next time) to narrow down a bit where the problem could be.

Comment: Also given you changed how you handle multi-tenancy, it could well be the tenant that is not being set/cleared correctly.  So when it fails you are actually running a test on a different tenant from what you expected simply because of the different order the tests run in.  I fell into exactly this trap and it wasn't easy to get out :p

Comment: I have `config.order = "defined"` in my spec helper.

Comment: Seems to be `default` in v2.x (2.8 onwards) and `defined` in v3.0.