# login_as with rspec fails first test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Following instructions from that [Devise How-To page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara) I'm trying to rebuild all my rspec test to bypass user signin process.

There are 2 methods that can be used for that:

1. `sign_in` from Devise - which can't be used with feature tests (Capybara)
2. `login_as` from Warden (Devise is build on top of it)

1st method at the first shot worked (all test passes) except those with Capybara so I decided to leave it for now.

2nd gives me some weird results - all passes except the first one (any which I place as the first in the file). It fails when I run just one of them. I've checked it with `binding.pry` and it fails as the user is not logged in and it redirects to the login page. Somehow first test triggers something that makes all the rest passing. I have no clue what's going on here.

I was using `around` hook before but it [behaves really weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792912/pgundefinedtable-error-relation-does-not-exist) so I've changed that to set of `before` and `after` (at the same time it works much faster as it creates just one user at the begging rather than for every test). This is how it looks like now:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AlbumsController do

  let(:album) { create(:album) }

  before(:all) do
    @user = create :user
  end

  before(:each) do
    login_and_switch_schema @user
  end

  after(:all) do
    destroy_users_schema @user
    destroy_user @user
  end

  describe "GET #new" do
    before { get :new }
    it { expect(response).to render_template :new }
  end

  describe "GET #edit" do
    before { get :edit, id: album }
    it { expect(response).to render_template :edit }
  end

  ...
```

and I've defined that helpers:

```
Warden.test_mode!

def login_and_switch_schema(user) 
 #@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
 #sign_in :user, user
 login_as(user, scope: :user)
 Apartment::Database.switch(user.username) 
end

def destroy_users_schema(user)
  Apartment::Database.drop(user.username)
  Apartment::Database.reset
end

def destroy_user(user)
  User.destroy(user)
end
```

I would like to ask you for help.

Answer (score 1):

I would try moving your `before(:all)` and `after(:all)` code into the `before(:each)` and `after(:each)`. `:all` doesn't play well with `let`, `DatabaseCleaner` or in giving you a predictable order of execution for the first test executed.