# In what order do RSpec's before, after and around hooks run?

Tags: ruby, rspec

As I faced [some issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808963/login-as-with-rspec-fails-first-test) I decided to check in what order `before` and `after` hooks are executed. This is what I did:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "The order:" do

  before(:all) {
    puts "before_all"
  }

  after(:all) {
    puts "after_all"
  }

  before(:each) {
    puts "before_each"
  }

  after(:each) {
    puts "after_each"
  }

  describe "DESC A" do
    before {
      puts "A_before"
    }
    it "A_it_1" do      
      expect(1).to eq(1)
    end
    it "A_it_2" do
      expect(1).to eq(1)
    end
  end

  describe "DESC B" do
    before {
      puts "B_before"
    }
    it "B_it_1" do      
      expect(1).to eq(1)
    end
    it "B_it_2" do
      expect(1).to eq(1)
    end
  end  
end
```

and what I got:

```
The order:

before_all

  DESC A
before_each
A_before
after_each
    A_it_1
before_each
A_before
after_each
    A_it_2
  DESC B
before_each
B_before
after_each
    B_it_1
before_each
B_before
after_each
    B_it_2

after_all
```

What is going on here ?? Why is `after_each` run before `A_it_1` ?

**UPDATE:**

adding `around(:each)` is even more fun:

```
 around(:each) do |example|
    puts "around_in"
    example.run
    puts "around_out"
  end
```

and results:

```
The order:
before_all
  DESC A
around_in
before_each
A_before
after_each
around_out
    A_it_1
around_in
before_each
A_before
after_each
around_out
    A_it_2
  DESC B
around_in
before_each
B_before
after_each
around_out
    B_it_1
around_in
before_each
B_before
after_each
around_out
    B_it_2
after_all
```

Comment: From the rspec documentation on before and after hooks, I see the dot for successful test is also exactly where you see it, i.e. AFTER the after(:each) trace - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#before/after-blocks-are-run-in-order

Comment: wow, great you've found it. It proves that this behaviour is known but what's the logic behind it ? Why one should expect that the `after(:each)` hook will be executed **before** the test ?

Comment: Could you try putting the `after(:each)` block AFTER the `describe` blocks in your spec file and see what happens?

Comment: Just did it and nothing have changed (at least).

Comment: I just tried your example; looks like `puts` is not a reliable method to determine the order.  When I stuck a debugger statement in `after(:each)` and before and after the test in `A_it_1` it did actually behave as expected.  Looks like a gotcha with using puts?

Comment: Naa.. worked as above - using `binding.pry` I can confirm that `after_each` is run before `A_it_1`

Answer (score 8):

Your output, and the official output documented on relishapp.com, are correct. What's happening is that rspec needs to run the after(:each)es after each example, because an exception in an after(:each) would cause the example to fail. Before rspec can display the example in the output, it needs to know whether it is green or red, which means the after(:eaches) need to be run before the example's description appears in the output.

However, if you put a puts statement in your actual example, you will see that the before(:each)es occur before it, then the example code is run (including the puts), then the after(:each)es, just as you would expect, and finally, the description of the example is output to screen.

Like you, I was also confused, until I realized that rspec printing out the example's label doesn't coincide with what it's actually doing -- the label only gets printed out once all the before(:all)s, before(:each)es, and after(:each)es are run for the example.

Note: after(:all)s get run after the example label is printed out, because they do not affect the outcome of the test (a warning is generated that an exception occurred in an after(:all) hook, but this does not make a test go red).

Answer (score 7):

[RSpec's documentation for `before` and `after` hooks](http://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-core/hooks/before-and-after-hooks/) specifies the order in which they run. However, [RSpec's documentation for `around` hooks](http://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-core/hooks/around-hooks/) doesn't specify the order in which they run.

This spec tests the order in which `around`, `before` and `after` `:all` and `:each`, and examples, execute. When I run it with rspec(-core) 2.14.8, they execute in the order you'd expect:

```
describe "order in which rspec around/before/after hooks run" do
  before :all do
    defined?($previous_hook).should be_false # this hook runs first
    $previous_hook = "before :all"
  end
  
  around :each do |example|
    $previous_hook.should == "before :all"
    $previous_hook = "around :each 1"
    example.run
    $previous_hook.should == "after :each"
    $previous_hook = "around :each 2"
  end

  before :each do
    $previous_hook.should == "around :each 1"
    $previous_hook = "before :each"
  end
  
  it "should not raise an exception or print anything" do
    $previous_hook.should == "before :each"
    $previous_hook = "example"
  end
  
  after :each do
    $previous_hook.should == "example"
    $previous_hook = "after :each"
  end
  
  after :all do
    # rspec ignores assertion failures and any other exceptions raised here, so all we can do is puts.
    # $previous_hook is a global because if it's an instance variable it is "before :all" at this point.
    warn "Previous hook was #{$previous_hook}, NOT around :each 2 as expected" unless $previous_hook == "around :each 2"
  end

end
```

Note some possibly surprising things:

- `self` is different in `:all` and `:each` blocks, so I needed to use a global rather than an instance variable.
- `after :all` (but not `before :all`) eats exceptions.
- look at all those places `.should` works! Not that you'd normally want to use it there.

Comment: sorry, I'm so busy right now as I have to leave those things for a while but I'll not forget to came back here for sure as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered above, but to add an answer simple way.

To see in what order the hooks are running, you have to add "puts" statement inside "it" also

So

```
describe "The order:" do

  before(:all) {
    puts "before_all"
  }

  after(:all) {
    puts "after_all"
  }

  before(:each) {
    puts "before_each"
  }

  after(:each) {
    puts "after_each"
  }

  describe "DESC A" do
    before {
      puts "A_before"
    }
    it "A_it_1" do      
      # expect(1).to eq(1)       <<<<---- Change Here
      puts "Inside the test"
    end
  end
end
```