# Rspec - Devise login_as does not work on the first test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I have a controller spec that needs a super admin to be logged in to work

I followed [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Capybara) guide to and wrote the (paraphrased) following in my tests

```
before(:each) do
  super_admin = FactoryGirl.create(:super_admin)
  login_as super_admin, scope: :super_admin
end

it "does whatever" do
  get :whatever

  expect(whatever).to eq(whatever)
end

it "does something else" do
  get :something_else

  expect(something_else).to (something_else)
end
```

My problem is that the login is only working for tests past the first, debugging revealed that it was failing authentication, if I use before(:each) to login, and is failing every test except the first when i use before(:all)

I found [login_as with rspec fails first test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808963/login-as-with-rspec-fails-first-test) where the asker appears to be having a similar problem, but the only answer doesn't help me

Comment: what if you have your super_admin creation in `let` block?  `let(:super_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:super_admin) }
before { login_as(super_admin, scope: :super_admin) }`

Comment: no dice, results are the same

Comment: Can you show the RSpec failure(s)?

Comment: `Failure/Error: expect(whatever).to eq(whatever)

expected: whatever
            got: not_whatever
     
       (compared using ==)`.

using binding.pry I can see the super_admin is being created, if I manually use login_as in binding.pry it shows that there is already `#<Proc:memory address@/path_to/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/test/helpers.rb:18>` and it's creating another one, other debug code I added indicates that the super_admin authentication is failing

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. login_as(user) does not login the user in. I have set up the config as per documentation. Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like `login_as` doesn't play well with controller specs (I'm assuming), when I switched `login_as super_admin, scope: :super_admin` with `sign_in super_admin` everything started working